# get professional inside #dateHeaderTemplate in angular component schedule syncfusion

Tags: angular, typescript, schedule, syncfusion

I need to get inside the template `#dateHeaderTemplate` what is the id of the professional that is going, because I need to get the start time and end time of day and display in the header.

From this [link](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/?&_ga=2.247006275.674499638.1571572235-578596555.1563196694#/material/schedule/date-header-template) you can see that we can change the `#dateHeaderTemplate` header with customizable elements.

If there is a way for me to get the percussion value the same way I get in `#resourceHeaderTemplate` I can get the pro id.

**component.ts:**

```
  public getStartTimeAndEndTime(data): string {

    // values containing data
    // {date: Mon Oct 21 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora padrão de Brasília), type: "dateHeader"}

    // I need here a way to identify which professional is being covered

    return '13:30 - 18:30';
  }

  public getDateHeaderText(value: Date): string {
    return this.instance.formatDate(value, { skeleton: 'Ed' });
  }
```

**component.html:**

```
<ng-template #resourceHeaderTemplate let-data>

   <!-- here I have the professional id -->

    <div class='template-wrap'>
        <div class="avatar resource-image {{getDoctorImage(data)}}"></div>
        <div class="resource-details">
            <div class="resource-name">{{getDoctorName(data)}}</div>
            <div class="h6">{{ getEspecialidadeName(data) }}</div>
            <div class="h5 text-bold" [ngClass]="{'green-fg': getDoctorStatus(data).type === 'atendendo',
             'secondary-text': getDoctorStatus(data).type === 'away'  }">{{ getDoctorStatus(data).text }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #dateHeaderTemplate let-data>
    <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
        <div class="date-text h3 text-bold">{{getDateHeaderText(data.date)}}</div>
        <div class="h6">{{getStartTimeAndEndTime(data)}}</div>
        <!-- 
            Here besides getting the date I also need the professional id
             that comes inside the ng-template #resourceHeaderTemplate-->
    </div>
</ng-template>
<e-resources>
    <e-resource field='DoctorId' title='Doctor' name='Doctors' [dataSource]='resourceDataSource'
        textField='text' idField='id' colorField='color' workDaysField='workDays' startHourField='startHour'
        endHourField='endHour'>
    </e-resource>
</e-resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syncfusion Greetings.

We can’t get the resource id inside the dateHeaderTemplate instead of this we suggest you to use the scheduler's renderCell event to display the resource start and end hour on date header. Please refer below sample.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mf9hdq-au5ue2?file=app.component.ts

```
onRenderCell(args: RenderCellEventArgs): void {

  // Here we can retrieve resource data while rendering date header cells
  if (args.elementType == 'dateHeader') {
    let resData: any = this.scheduleObj.getResourcesByIndex(parseInt(args.element.getAttribute('data-group-index'), 10));
    let ele: HTMLElement = createElement('div', {
      innerHTML: ""+resData.resourceData.startHour +" - "+resData.resourceData.endHour,
      className: 'res-name', styles: 'padding-top: 5px'
    });
    (args.element).appendChild(ele);
  }
}
```